# C++ Style: When using c function in c++, should I check for NULL or nullptr?

Tags: c++

In a C++ program, if I want to use a c function that will return NULL for any error, should I check for `nullptr` or `NULL`?

```
int * ptr = someCfunction();
if (ptr == nullptr)
    return false;
```

or:

```
int * ptr = someCfunction();
if (ptr == NULL)
    return false;
```

Which one is better in terms of style?

Comment: Either way will work. `NULL` is defined as just `0`. `nullptr` is only available in C++11 and later, but comparing a pointer to `0` is still supported. If you are using C++11 or later, prefer `nullptr`, it is more explicit and less error prone (`nullptr` was added to address shortcoming of `NULL` handling)

Comment: This is a C++ question. That the API is written in C does not really require tagging this in C to push this to feeds of anyone following the C tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the cppreference on [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr), you can see that there is implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `NULL`. So you can do either but (as good practice) better use `nullptr` from C++11 onwards.

> The keyword `nullptr` denotes the pointer literal. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. There exist implicit conversions from `nullptr` to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any null pointer constant, which includes values of type `std::nullptr_t` **as well as the macro `NULL`**.

Comment: Maybe mention that `nullptr` prevents comparison with a non-pointer type (except for `bool`), which is one of the drawbacks of using `NULL`: `if (the_int_Ive_mistaken_for_a_ptr == nullptr)` doesn't compile, and would've if compared with `NULL`